# android sqlite - no such file, no such column

Tags: java, eclipse, sqlite

My problem is the following:

It was wrote on Console.

```
[2013-02-24 14:30:40 - AdatBpro] Android Launch!
[2013-02-24 14:30:40 - AdatBpro] adb is running normally.
[2013-02-24 14:30:40 - AdatBpro] Performing hu.AB.example.adatbpro.MainActivity activity launch
[2013-02-24 14:30:40 - AdatBpro] Automatic Target Mode: Unable to detect device compatibility. Please select a target device.
[2013-02-24 14:30:47 - AdatBpro] Launch canceled!
[2013-02-24 14:31:04 - AdatBpro] emulator-5554 disconnected! Cancelling 'hu.AB.example.adatbpro.MainActivity activity launch'!
[2013-02-24 14:42:15 - AdatBpro] ------------------------------
[2013-02-24 14:42:15 - AdatBpro] Android Launch!
[2013-02-24 14:42:15 - AdatBpro] adb is running normally.
[2013-02-24 14:42:15 - AdatBpro] Performing hu.AB.example.adatbpro.MainActivity activity launch
[2013-02-24 14:42:16 - AdatBpro] Automatic Target Mode: launching new emulator with compatible AVD 'AVD412'
[2013-02-24 14:42:16 - AdatBpro] Launching a new emulator with Virtual Device 'AVD412'
[2013-02-24 14:42:16 - Emulator] WARNING: Data partition already in use. Changes will not persist!
[2013-02-24 14:42:16 - Emulator] WARNING: SD Card image already in use: C:\Users\Edit\.android\avd\AVD412.avd/sdcard.img
[2013-02-24 14:42:16 - Emulator] WARNING: Cache partition already in use. Changes will not persist!
[2013-02-24 14:42:16 - AdatBpro] New emulator found: emulator-5556
[2013-02-24 14:42:16 - AdatBpro] Waiting for HOME ('android.process.acore') to be launched...
[2013-02-24 14:43:32 - AdatBpro] HOME is up on device 'emulator-5556'
[2013-02-24 14:43:32 - AdatBpro] Uploading AdatBpro.apk onto device 'emulator-5556'
[2013-02-24 14:43:33 - AdatBpro] Installing AdatBpro.apk...
[2013-02-24 14:44:30 - AdatBpro] Success!
```

The program is runing and database open but when the first emulator wrote nothing. 
I try again run. The first emulator is there open and open the second emulator and wrote everything on the second emulator.

Its only made on emulator.

it does not run on a telephone.

Why make this? What I made wrong?

I can not find the solution.

public class DbConstants {

```
public static final String DATABASE_NAME = "tar.db";
public static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;
public static String DATABASE_CREATE_ALL = Todo.DATABASE_CREATE;
public static String DATABASE_DROP_ALL = Todo.DATABASE_DROP;

public static class Todo {
    // public static final String DATABASE_NAME = "data.db";
    public static final String DATABASE_TABLE = "todo";
    public static final String KEY_ROWID = "_id";
    public static final String KEY_KI = "ki";


    public static final String DATABASE_CREATE = "create table if not exists "
            + DATABASE_TABLE
            + "("
            + KEY_ROWID
            + " integer primary key autoincrement, "
            + KEY_KI
            + " text );";  

    public static final String DATABASE_DROP = "drop table if exists"
            + DATABASE_TABLE + "; ";




    private long id;
    private String ki;




    public Todo(String aKi)
    {

        ki = aKi;

    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return ki;
    }

    public long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getKi() {
        return ki;
    }

    public void setKi(String ki) {
        this.ki = ki;
    }


}
```

}

public class MainActivity extends ListActivity {

private TodoCursorAdapter Adapter;

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
//  setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    TodoDbLoader dbLoader = new TodoDbLoader(getApplicationContext());
    dbLoader.open();
    Cursor c = dbLoader.fetchAll();


    if (c.getCount() == 0) {
        dbLoader.createTodo(new Todo("ÉN"));
        dbLoader.createTodo(new Todo("Sári"));
        dbLoader.createTodo(new Todo("Saci"));

        c = dbLoader.fetchAll();
    }
    c.moveToFirst();
    Adapter = new TodoCursorAdapter(getApplicationContext(), c);
    setListAdapter(Adapter);
}
```

}

public class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

```
public DatabaseHelper(Context context, String name){
    super(context, name, null, DbConstants.DATABASE_VERSION);
}

@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    db.execSQL(DbConstants.DATABASE_CREATE_ALL);

}

@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    db.execSQL(DbConstants.DATABASE_DROP_ALL);
    db.execSQL(DbConstants.DATABASE_CREATE_ALL);
}
```

}

public class TodoDbLoader{

```
private Context ctx;
private DatabaseHelper dbHelper;
private SQLiteDatabase mDb;

public TodoDbLoader(Context ctx){
    this.ctx= ctx;
}
public void open()throws SQLException{
    dbHelper = new  DatabaseHelper(ctx,DbConstants.DATABASE_NAME);
    mDb = dbHelper.getWritableDatabase();
    dbHelper.onCreate(mDb);
}

public void close(){
    dbHelper.close();
}

public long createTodo(Todo todo){
    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    values.put(DbConstants.Todo.KEY_KI, todo.getKi());


    return mDb.insert(DbConstants.Todo.DATABASE_TABLE, null, values);
}

public boolean deleteTodo(long rowId){

    return mDb.delete(
            DbConstants.Todo.DATABASE_TABLE,
            DbConstants.Todo.KEY_ROWID + "=" + rowId, null) > 
    0;
}

public boolean deleteAllTodo(){
    return mDb.delete(DbConstants.Todo.DATABASE_TABLE , null, null) > 0;
}

public boolean updateProduct(long rowId, Todo newTodo){
    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();

    values.put(DbConstants.Todo.KEY_KI, newTodo.getKi());

    return mDb.update(DbConstants.Todo.DATABASE_TABLE,
            values,
            DbConstants.Todo.KEY_ROWID + "=" + rowId, null) > 
    0;
}

public Cursor fetchAll(){
    return mDb.query(DbConstants.Todo.DATABASE_TABLE, 
            new String[]{ DbConstants.Todo.KEY_ROWID,
            DbConstants.Todo.KEY_KI,
             }, null, null, null, null, DbConstants.Todo.KEY_KI);


}

public Todo fetchTodo(long rowId){
    Cursor c = mDb.query(DbConstants.Todo.DATABASE_TABLE, 
            new String[]{ DbConstants.Todo.KEY_ROWID,
            DbConstants.Todo.KEY_KI,
             },DbConstants.Todo.KEY_ROWID + "=" + rowId,
            null, null, null, DbConstants.Todo.KEY_KI);
    if (c.moveToFirst())
        return getTodoByCursor(c);
    return null;

}

public static Todo getTodoByCursor(Cursor c){
    return new Todo(                
            c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(DbConstants.Todo.KEY_KI)) 
            );
}
```

}

public class TodoCursorAdapter extends CursorAdapter {

```
public TodoCursorAdapter(Context context, Cursor c){
    super(context, c, false);
}



@Override
public View newView(Context context, Cursor cursor, ViewGroup parent) {

    final LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
    View row = inflater.inflate(R.layout.todorow, null);
    bindView(row, context, cursor);
    return row;
}

@Override
public void bindView(View view, Context context, Cursor cursor) {

    TextView KiTV = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textViewKi);

    Todo todo = TodoDbLoader.getTodoByCursor(cursor);

    KiTV.setText(todo.getKi());


}
@Override
public Todo getItem(int position) {
    getCursor().moveToPosition(position);

    return TodoDbLoader.getTodoByCursor(getCursor());
}
```

}

Comment: Always post **full** StackTrace or error messages.

Comment: it cant find your database judging by the error message! looks like you didn't specific the correct paths to database

Comment: its very good to find the database. why write nothing?